# How do you remake a spellbook?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, crafting

My wizard's spellbook was destroyed! How can I acquire/create a new one?

Comment: Sorry its for 5e

Comment: [Related] [How does a Ritual Caster (feat) replace their ritual book?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/55123) • [Can a wizard copy prepared spells into a spellbook?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/59548)

Answer (score 6):

A spellbook costs 50 gp and should be available in most towns for purchase (depending on setting). You can then copy all of the spells into it that you have prepared, using the procedure on page 114 of the PHB.

This item could be crafted according to the mundane crafting rules in the PHB (p. 187).

Answer (score 3):

I believe the general rule is **you can use any other book**. From the 5e book on p.114, note the absence of qualifiers on "another book":

> ***Replacing the Book.*** You can copy a spell from your own spellbook into another book — for example, if you want to make a backup copy of your spellbook. This is just like copying a new spell into your spellbook, but faster and easier, since you understand your own notation and already know how to cast the spell. You need spend only 1 hour and 10 gp for each level of the copied spell.
>
> If you lose your spellbook, you can use the same procedure to transcribe the spells that you have prepared into a new spellbook. Filling out the remainder of your spellbook requires you to find new spells to do so, as normal. For this reason, many wizards keep backup spellbooks in a safe place.

You cannot remake the book, any empty book can serve you as a spellbook, but if you lost all your original spells, you have to start again from scratch.

You can find most of those rulings in the Wizard class section of the handbook however, the best solution is usually to discuss it with your DM

Comment: You cannot use "any book". Spellbook is a specific entry on the equipment list. It costs twice as much as a regular book from the same list.

Comment: An absence of a qualifier in one place does not qualify its absence in general.  See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evidence_of_absence

Comment: Yes you can use any book. You could even use random scraps of parchment, as described on page 114 at the end of the "Your Spellbook" sidebar.

Comment: If i were to craft a book what would i need.

Comment: Leatherworking tools to make the vellum pages and the thick leather cover, then a needle and thick thread to bind it. See the mundane crafting rules on page 187, as Derek's answer says.

Comment: Are there alternatives for using a spellbook like writing them on a staff or embedded into something else?

Comment: You could conceivably write on anything that could possibly be written on. The only limitation is that you must still abide by the gold costs in the PHB for copying spells from spellbook to spellbook.